# Как поставить View элемент по центру экрана?

Tags: ios, swift

Вот есть у меня `ViewController` и мне нужно поставить `ImageView` по центру экрана.

Я значит хватаю это вью и ставлю его по середине так, чтоб вертикально и горизонтально появились линии.

Но когда переключаю между экранами разных устройств, то этот центр смещается...

Если протягивать `Trailling` то он просто фиксирует расстояние до краев и таким образом растягивает мое View на большом экране...

Попробовал найти в гугле, но такое впечатление, что такая проблема только у меня

Как поставить View по центру, чтоб на всех экранах оно было по центру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинками здесь проще объяснить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и выставьте необходимые высоту/ширину картинки.

Comment: Я добавил зависимости по вертикали и горизонтали, но все равно, на одном устройстве это выглядит нормально, когда переключаю на другой экран, то все равно сьежает...